# Amcharts click event in Angular 2 not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amcharts

Here is my codebase

```
        export class myComponent implements OnInit {
          minHist;
          maxHist;
        }

        public callAmcharts(whichFilterType:String){

                    this.amchart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chart", {
                      "type": "serial",
                      "theme": "light",
                      "dataProvider": this.TrendData,
                      "valueAxes": [ {
                        "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
                        "gridAlpha": 0.2,
                        "dashLength": 0
                      }],
                      "gridAboveGraphs": true,
                      "startDuration": 1,
                      "graphs": [ {
                        "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
                        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                        "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                        "type": "column",
                        "valueField": "dCount",
                        "showHandOnHover":true
                      } ],

                      "chartCursor": {
                        "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                        "cursorAlpha": 0,
                        "zoomable": false
                      },
                      "categoryField": "dRange",
                      "categoryAxis": {
                        "gridPosition": "start",
                        "gridAlpha": 0,
                        "tickPosition": "start",
                        "tickLength": 20,
                        "labelRotation": 45
                      },
                      "export": {
                        "enabled": true
                      }

                    });

   this.amchart.addListener("clickGraphItem",this.myfunc);
```

}

Now onclick event `myfunc` is getting called . But strangely I cant access any global variable there using `this`. If its a `scope` issue it should give error while calling `myfunc` also right?

```
public myfunc(e:any){
        var range= e.item.category;
        let range_arr = range.split("-");
        this.minHist=range_arr[0];
        this.maxHist=range_arr[1];

    }
```

I am getting error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'minHist' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this.amchart.addListener("clickGraphItem",this.myfunc);
```

to

```
this.amchart.addListener("clickGraphItem",this.myfunc.bind(this));
```

Depending on your inputs this will also work:

```
this.amchart.addListener("clickGraphItem",(e)=> this.myfunc(e));
```

which is the shorter version of:

```
this.amchart.addListener("clickGraphItem",(e)=> { return this.myfunc(e); });
```

Suggested reading: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Yes that was a nice article. Thanks for the answer too it worked.